# sql server 2012 - summing columns with one or more inputs depending on error message

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, case, multiple-columns

I have a table that looks like the below:

```
[booking_id] [generation_time] [original_booking_id]
```

I have managed to work out the `AVG [generation_time]` for all `[booking_id]`

However, In the case where `[original_booking_id]` is not zero, I'd like to add the total generation time for the `[booking_id]`

In these cases, I should ignore all `[booking_id]` with an `[original_booking_id]` as these are more components of another booking, rather then something to me measured on its own.

I want to know, in total, the `[generation_time]` for all `[booking_id]`

I hope this is clear - any assistance appreciated.

Comment: Please tag the question with the exact DBMS you are using. Also including the sample data and expected output would help.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand this would help you

```
select booking_id,SUM(generation_time)
from bookings
where booking_id<>original_booking_id AND original_booking_id<>0
group by booking_id
```

This will elimiante records with original_booking_id=0 and booking_id=original_booking_id.

Comment: This is great, thank you. Ive added to my query. However, it seems that it is not summing the total generation time for each booking_id - it is just removing the records where an original_booking_id is present and summing the rest?

Comment: Can you elaborate what expected output is?

Comment: I'd be expecting data like so ---- [booking_id], [generation_time], [generation_time_of_other-bookings_linked_to_this_one] as gen2, ([generation_time + [gen2] as TotalTimeTakenForThisBooking group by [booking_id] - or something similar - sorry if I'm not clear - If I could show the generation time of bookings that are linked to the original booking_id I could make it look nice in excel (sorry also for lack of paragraphs)

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that you want the following: The average generation time grouped by booking_id where original_booking_id is zero + generation_time for each booking_id where original_booking_id is not zero.

You could use a CTE, or subquery, to archieve this.

;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 
          booking_id
        , original_booking_id
        , AVG(generation_time) AS generation_time
    FROM #bookings
    GROUP BY booking_id, original_booking_id
)
SELECT 
      booking_id
    , SUM(generation_time)
FROM cte 
GROUP BY booking_id